# this.props.navigation.navigate() is undefined

Tags: react-native

I am using createStackNavigator like this.

```
const ChatStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profiles: Profiles,
  ChatScreen: ChatScreen
})

const RootChatStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: ChatStack,
  ModalScreen: ProfileModalScreen
},{
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  })
```

In Profiles I use `props.navigation.navigate('ChatScreen',{name: item.content })` to go to ChatScreen.

And In ChatScreen

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
    title: navigation.getParam('name', ''),
  };
 ...
  renderModal() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ModalScreen')
  }
 ...
 }
```

I can set title using navigationOptions, but when I use this.renderModal(),
It gives me Error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation')
```

How I can use navigation.navigate inside Example Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `class` based react components you have to bind additional functions in your components to the instance. You would do so by explicitly binding `this` to each additional function in your component (react functions like `render()` are already bound).

This is the key line in the snippet below:
`this.renderModal = this.renderModal.bind(this);`

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderModal = this.renderModal.bind(this);
  }

  renderModal() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ModalScreen');
  }

  ...
 }
```